# correct accessing of slices with duplicate index-values present

Tags: pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe with an index that sometimes contains rows with the same index-value. Now I want to slice that dataframe and set values based on row-indices.

Consider the following example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'index':[1,2,2,3], 'values':[10,20,30,40]})
df.set_index(['index'], inplace=True)

df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()

#copy warning
df1.iloc[0:2]['values'] = 99
print(df1)

df2.loc[df.index[0:2], 'values'] = 99
print(df2)
```

df1 is the expected result, but gives me a SettingWithCopyWarning.
df2 seems to be the suggested way of accessing by the doc, but gives me the wrong result (because of the duplicate index)

Is there a "proper" way to set those values correctly with the duplicate index-values present?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.loc` is not recommended when you have duplicate index. So you have to go for position based selection [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html). Since we need to pass the positions, we have to use [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for getting position of column:

```
print (df2.columns.get_loc('values'))
0

df1.iloc[0:2, df2.columns.get_loc('values')] = 99
print(df1)
       values
index        
1          99
2          99
2          30
3          40
```

Comment: @Bharath - Thank you.