# Python: An alternative way to access an element in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda dataframe:

```
df
Out[168]: 
            max_speed  shield
cobra               4       2
viper               4       5
sidewinder          7       8

df.loc['cobra' , 'max_speed']
Out[169]: 4
```

Is there any way to access the same element in the data frame by "column/row number", like

```
df.loc[0,0]
```

?

df.loc[0,0] does not work, though.

Comment: Use `df.iloc[0,0]`

Comment: Thank you. That works!! How could we access via both numbers and column names? df.iloc[0:2,'max_speed'] does not work.

Comment: Check seelcting in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47530736/correct-accessing-of-slices-with-duplicate-index-values-present/47530787#47530787)